Create a market ID from Origin destination pair in Python
I have given an example here
       data = {
            "Origin": ["DEL", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "LHR", "SRE", "RLK", "ZUN"],
            "Destination": ["LHR", "FDE", "SRE", "FTU", "DEL", "ABC", "ZUN", "RLK"],
            "ORD": ["DELLHR", "ABCFDE", "ABCSRE", "ABCFTU", "LHRDEL", "SREABC", "RLKZUN", "ZUNRLK"]
        }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ORD']=df['Origin]+df['Destination']

I wan to create a coumn of Market_Id like this from the data

The ORD for 1st riw of the ORD column is DELLHR and the 5th row is LHRDEL. However, the Market_ID is DELLHR for both.
Help me code this.
